# Deriving the code for these three matrices

Tags: matrices

I would like to kindly ask if someone is able to derive the code for the following :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code below is for the first matrix as it is easy to write for three matrices.

```
$\begin{matrix}
& A & \\
& \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        a & b & c
    \end{bmatrix} &\\
& \mbox{Input matrix} & \\
\end{matrix}$
```

I write this code by imagining that the block is a matrix with three rows, where the second row is another matrix.

Answer (score 3):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-row=6]
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small A}} \\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\rule{0pt}{12pt}
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small Input matrix} }
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}
$\rightarrow$ \\
\small Phase 1
\end{tabular}
%
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-row=6]
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small U}}\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
0 & \times & \times & \times & \times \\
0 & 0 & \times & \times & \times\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \times & \times\\
\rule{0pt}{12pt}
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small Upper Hessenberg}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
%
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}
$\rightarrow$ \\
\small Phase 2
\end{tabular} 
%
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-row=6]
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small T}}\\
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
0 & \times & \times & \times & \times\\
0 & 0 & \times & \times & \times \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \times & \times\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \times\\
\rule{0pt}{12pt}
\Block{1-5}{\text{\small Upper Triangular}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}$                                                                                     
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Just my humble comment. Peraphs it is better to write a bit below the "Input matrix" etc. a bit more lower. +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Your are right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Not problem: my was only a suggestion to have a more nice code :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 
 
 \begin{document}
 \noindent{}

 \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    {\small A}            &                               & {\small U}                &   & {\small T}                \\
    $\begin{bmatrix}
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times \\%
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
            \end{bmatrix}
    $                     &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{c}
            $\rightarrow$ \\\small Phase 1
    \end{tabular}
                          & $\begin{bmatrix}
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    0 & \times & \times & \times & \times \\%
                    0 & 0 & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    0 & 0 & 0 & \times & \times\\%
            \end{bmatrix}  $ & \begin{tabular}[c]{c}
            $\rightarrow$ \\\small Phase 2
    \end{tabular} &
    $\begin{bmatrix}
                    \times & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    0 & \times & \times & \times & \times\\%
                    0 & 0 & \times & \times & \times \\%
                    0 & 0 & 0 & \times & \times\\%
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \times\\%
            \end{bmatrix}  $                                                                                     \\
    {\small Input matrix} &                               & {\small Upper Hessenberg} &   & {\small Upper Triangular}
 \end{tabular}
 \end{document}
```

[image: pmatrix]